# Embed an external program inside a java program

Tags: java

I'm implementing a patch in Jabref (reference management software): I want to embed a pdf reader in it. This feature has been done in Mendeley and Papers, and it's very useful if you can read/markup pdfs right inside of Jabref.

Instead of writing a pdf viewer, I want to embed outside program inside Jabref, such as Adobe Reader, or PDF Document Viewer in Ubuntu. Is there anyway to do that?